# Opemmp segment Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

I need a little help here. Im try to use opemmp and i have a seg fault. When i comment #pragma... the program run normal, but with #pragma i got seg and much more warnings, i dont know what im doing wrong, i new on opemmp and any help will be welcome.
here is my code.

http://pastebin.com/KXrkxQXx

I compile with -g3 to gdb, but say the seg fault occour on

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff70eb700 (LWP 19010)]
0x0000000000400c5a in condicoes_iniciais ()
```

Thanks for help. and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your code completely, but I have seen an error that I can tell you.

In line 125, you allocate memory for `xnew` and in line 140 you make this pointer private to every thread. When you declare a variable as private in OpenMP, its value is undefined at the beginning, so you are missing the address to the allocated memory. For example:

```
int a = 10;
#pragma omp parallel private(a)
{
  a += 5; // wrong, a is not initialized in the thread
}
```

To solve that issue, declare `xnew` as `firstprivate`. The same happens with the other variables.

Comment: in the line 146 i make all initialization of xnew and other. I make then private because i not whant other threads changer their values.

Comment: I make this changes to check if work. Well now the seg fault is on parametro_ordem function.

Comment: The problem is that in line 146 you store values in arrays `xold` and so on, but they don't point to your allocated memory if they are omp-private.

Comment: I change then all to first private. in gdb i got now
    (gdb) where
    #0  0x00000000004013b4 in parametro_ordem ()
    #1  0x0000000000401cfa in main._omp_fn.0 ()
    #2  0x00007ffff78d7eea in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
    #3  0x00007ffff76bae9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    #4  0x00007ffff73e7ccd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    #5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Comment: Sorry, the code is quite complex to debug online, but I think you don't allocate enough memory in variable `T`.

Comment: I was think the same. but with all in malloc can not be enough? And if i commend #pragma line, and remove all opemmp variable the code work well.